# Array of objects class instantiation

Tags: php, oop

Hello I'm having some trouble creating an array that should hold all the instances of my class. For example I'd like that everytime I instantiate an object from my main class to automatically put that object in an empty array created previously in the class.

```
    class Meniu_de_baza{   
        private $nume;
        private $descriere_ro;
        private $descriere_en;
        private $pret;
        private $array_obiecte[];

        function __construct($n,$d_ro,$d_en,$p){
            $this->nume = $n;
            $this->descriere_ro = $d_ro;
            $this->descriere_en = $d_en;
            $this->pret = $p;
            $this-array_obiecte = $this-

        }

        function getPret(){
            return $this->pret;
        }

        function setPret($set_pret){
            if(is_numeric($set_pret)){
                $this->pret = $set_pret;
            }else{
                echo "Pretul este invalid!";
            }
        }

        function detalii_mancare(){
            echo "Ati comandat {$this->nume} ce contine: <br />" . "{$this->descriere_ro} <br />";
        }

        function nota_plata(){
            echo "Nota Plata: <br />{$this->nume} 1 portie <br /> TOTAL: {$this->pret} RON";
        }
}
```

> > The code is attached as an image due to an issue I've occured trying to put it in a code block. Thanks in advance. Any advice is appreciated.[image: Here is the class]

Comment: What issue? I suggest you put it in your question as text anyway, if you can't format it correctly the community will edit it.

Comment: That is unreadable. Paste the text here. It's not that hard.

Comment: Create global array and pass one around in your instances but... Why do you want that?

Comment: I kept getting errors at the heredoc ... that's why I preffered the photo but I've put the main class here I hope it's readable now.

Comment: @Leri, I need this because this is basically a restaurant menu class that I need for a table in html. I was thinking to add all my objects and after that foreaching them to display them in a corner of an web application.

Comment: @SAdrian please check my answer it might help you

Comment: @user2907171 I'm going to try it now and let you know if it worked, thanks for replying on such a short notice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small example

```
class Sample{
    private static $objects=array();

     public function __construct()
    {
        static::$objects[]=$this;
    }

    public function getObjects(){
         return static::$objects;
    }

}
```

declare that field as static so variable will be at class level not at object level.

**How to use:**

```
new Sample();
new Sample();
new Sample();

$a=new Sample();

var_dump($a->getObjects());
```

Hope this might help you

**EDIT FOR YOUR CODE:**

```
class Meniu_de_baza{   
        private $nume;
        private $descriere_ro;
        private $descriere_en;
        private $pret;
        private static $array_obiecte[];

        function __construct($n,$d_ro,$d_en,$p){
            $this->nume = $n;
            $this->descriere_ro = $d_ro;
            $this->descriere_en = $d_en;
            $this->pret = $p;
            static::$array_obiecte[] = $this;

        }

        function getPret(){
            return $this->pret;
        }

        function setPret($set_pret){
            if(is_numeric($set_pret)){
                $this->pret = $set_pret;
            }else{
                echo "Pretul este invalid!";
            }
        }

        function detalii_mancare(){
            echo "Ati comandat {$this->nume} ce contine: <br />" . "{$this->descriere_ro} <br />";
        }

        function nota_plata(){
            echo "Nota Plata: <br />{$this->nume} 1 portie <br /> TOTAL: {$this->pret} RON";
        }
```

**Problem with your code :**

you forgot semicolon at `static::$array_obiecte = $this;`

Comment: I get an error on this line of code in the constructor:>>static::$array_obiecte[]=$this;

Comment: have you made variable `static`?

Comment: private static $array_obiecte = array();

Comment: you forgot semicolon `;`

Comment: If I try with private static $array_obiecte[];  i get an error and if i try with private static $array_obiecte = array(); i keep getting the same error... >>Fatal error: Cannot access property Salate_si_gustari::$array_obiecte

Comment: you can not access private property outside class and to get that you either have to make it public or create method using which you can get that variable